# How to do async/await logic in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

I want to do this simple logic:

1. I have observable that returns value
2. I want to use that value and run sequentially two another observables
3. I want to return value based on my first observables after two sequential finished

this is my attempt to solve my problem with comments

```js
updateAvatar(
    @Headers() headers: { authorization: string },
    @CurrentUserId() currentUserId: string,
    @UploadedFile() avatarFile: Express.Multer.File,
  ): Observable<{ avatarUrl: string }> {
    const obs1 = this.queue.send(
      PostCommands.uploadImage,
      new UploadImageCommandRequst(
        currentUserId,
        avatarFile.originalname,
        'avatars',
        true,
      ),
    ); // returns observable
    const obs2 = obs1.pipe(
      map(({ imageUploadUrl, imageUrl }) => {
        // need await here
        this.httpService.put(imageUploadUrl, avatarFile.buffer); // returns observable
        // also need await here. patch must be executed after put
        this.httpService.patch(
          `${this.config.GATEWAY_URL}/user/profile`,
          {
            avatarUrl: imageUrl,
          },
          { headers: { authorization: headers.authorization } },
        ); // returns observable
        // value must be returned after patch executed
        return {
          avatarUrl: imageUrl,
        };
      }),
    );
    return obs2;
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) and [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/mergeMap) operators yet?

Comment: @stealththeninja Yes, I have. But I don't understand how to use them in my case

Answer (score 0):

I think either `switchMap` or `mergeMap` are needed. The important difference is `switchMap` will restart if a newer event emits from `obs1` and only emit newest. If you want to emit from all events by `obs1` then `mergeMap` might be what you want.

- switchMap operator docs: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/switchMap
- merge map operator docs: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/mergeMap

There's still more you could play with this: it's nested to get access to `imageUploadUrl` and `imageUrl` parameters, you might instead map these out from observable (A) and flatten the pipe slightly.

```js
const obs2 = obs1.pipe(
  switchMap(({ imageUploadUrl, imageUrl }) =>
    //
    // (A) Projecting event from obs1 to a new observable:
    // PUT request to image upload URL.
    //
    this.httpService.put(imageUploadUrl, avatarFile.buffer).pipe(
      // 
      // (B) After observable (A) emits, we PATCH user profile
      // 
      switchMap(() => this.httpService.patch(
          `${this.config.GATEWAY_URL}/user/profile`,
          { avatarUrl: imageUrl, },
          { headers: { authorization: headers.authorization } },
        )
      ),
      //
      // (C) Finally, we wanted to return the avatar URL. We map it
      // so this is what is resolved by (A)
      //
      map(() => ({ avatarUrl: imageUrl, })),
    )
  ),
);
```